# ramda filter only returning first result

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given an array of attributes on an element (from console window)
[image]

I need to **retreive** all the **'id', or 'name'** attributes

When executing this:

```
R.filter(R.where({name: R.or(R.equals('name'), R.equals('id'))}), attr)
```

I get the 'name' attribute.
[image]

When reversing the 'or' arguments thusly:

```
R.filter(R.where({name: R.or(R.equals('id'), R.equals('name'))}), attr)
```

I get the 'id' attribute:
[image]

the **filter** method should be returning all the **matching items** in an **array** - what am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`R.or`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#or) is expecting two boolean arguments, though you're passing it two functions ([`R.equals`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals)) that return boolean values instead. You should be able to swap out the use of `R.or` with [`R.either`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#either), which takes two predicate functions like you have and your filter should do what you expect.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's absolutely correct as I have worded it. What I really need to know if there is an equivalent method that takes more than just two arguments. Like `any`, which seems to have the same problem as `or`. Is there such a method?